# Convention for context menu

Tags: telerik, caliburn.micro

I was wondering if it's possible to write a convention that permits me to perform operations at context menu opening when the context menu is placed inside a radgrid

As I ve seen it's not possible to bind an event to a function...but maybe I'm wrong
Thansk

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView from Telerik? works just fine with context menus.  How are you trying to do it?

Comment: can you please help me on this?

Comment: I can't help without some extra information, like how you are wiring up your contextmenu's on RadGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the main problem I ve is that when I choose selection unit=cells I don't have the selecteditem selected... I wish that with right click it automatically updates my selected item puttin in the convention the contextmenu.getclickeditem()... Do you know if it's possible?
Thanks